# Javascript - Creating table with handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have an index.html where I have a div for table, that I am populating with javascript:

```
<div class="table-responsive table-hover">
  <table class="table" id="table">
  </table>
</div>
```

I have created handlebar template file:

```
<tr>
  <td>{{ avatar }}</td>
  <td>{{ name }}</td>
  <td>{{ homepage }}</td>
  <td>{{ score }}</td>
</tr>
```

In my script I am importing the template and trying to send data which is an array of objects that I get from an api endpoint, I am doing a `forEach` loop on an `array` of objects first, and calling a `createHtml` function:

```
var tableTemplate = require('../../templates/table.handlebars');

var createHtml = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var table = document.querySelector('#table');
    table.innerHTML = tableTemplate({
         avatar:  data.owner.avatar_url,
         name: data.full_name,
         homepage: data.homepage,
         score: data.score
    });
}

array.forEach(createHtml);
```

But, even though I get all the objects from the array logged in the console inside the function `createHtml`  only the first row for the table is being created, why is that, and how can I fix it?

**Update**

I have tried something like this, but I get table undefined:

```
var tableTemplate = require('../../templates/table.handlebars');

var createHtml = function(data) {
  console.log(data);

    table += tableTemplate({
         avatar_url:  data.owner.avatar_url,
         full_name: data.full_name,
         homepage: data.homepage,
     score: data.score
    });
}

export function createTable(repositories, page) {
  var itemsPerPage = 20,
      offset = page*20;

  table = document.querySelector('#table');
  table.innerHTML = '';

  repositories.slice(offset, offset+itemsPerPage).forEach(createHtml);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the HTML using innerHTML for each iteration, losing the HTML from the previous iteration. Concatenate all the strings and set the innerHTML once, outside the forEach. A better option (using only local variables) is to use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```
var tableTemplate = require('../../templates/table.handlebars');

document.querySelector('#table').innerHTML = array.map(function(data) {
    return tableTemplate({
         avatar:  data.owner.avatar_url,
         name: data.full_name,
         homepage: data.homepage,
         score: data.score
    });
}).join('');
```

Comment: Could you please provide me with a code example, not sure, how to do this, I would appreciate it alot! Thanks!

Comment: I can, if you try something and show what you tried. Basically you need to have a string defined outside of createHtml that you concat to inside createHtml, and you need to set innerHTML from outside createHtml using the string variable that you concatenated together.

Comment: I have tried something, I wonder if that was what you meant. Just can't get it to work. I have updated my question with my attempt.

Comment: @Leff In your attempt, you were supposed to concatenate all the HTML strings together into a `tableHTML` variable and then only after the forEach was finished, you would set `table.innerHTML = tableHTML`, I've added a solution that is more elegant.